# Drafts should save in Edit forms

Tags: support, feature-request, editor

I was under the impression that drafts of edits were saved. Is that not the case?

Now I lost one of my better answers in its inception because being on mobile and a bit clumsy I sometimes accidently hit the submit button and occasionally continue by editing, and then have to go back in the browser to e.g. to read the question body again. What drafts are and are not saved is not well documented anyhow, and might be subject to change. I'm just curious if I misremembered because the browser will have the text cached if going back and forth, but reloading by clicking the edit link will apparently refresh.

I'm tagging this feature-request, too, just to nag.

Comment: Drafts are not created for edits.

Comment: ...and the reason for that is that it would effectively either lock the post so no-one else could edit it in the meantime, or render your draft obsolete and waste its storage space if other edits are allowed.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Please close.

Answer (score 1):

On the app (iOS at least) edits are saved as drafts. Here’s an example:

[image: a screenshot that says question edit]

You don’t have to do anything special to save a draft; you can close the app and it will still be there.

I find that the app is a better mobile experience than the website in some ways like this, but a horrific unmaintained mess in many other ways.